# Improper spacing in the "share a link to this answer" template

Tags: bug

The "share a link to this answer" generates a text like this:

> Answer:Finding the longest common suffix recursively using javascript

I hope you notice that there is no space after "Answer:" and the text that follows (the question title). This is [improper spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Spacing), and it forces me to edit the text before sending. This is annoying.

This would be correct spacing:

> Answer: Finding the longest common suffix recursively using javascript

Can you please adjust the template?

Here's a screenshot too in case it helps:

[image]

Comment: Click on the Twitter icon. Then the popup changes, and the template text is filled in. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, the bug. I see it.